# Compare and sync two database contextes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, synchronization, dbcontext

I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB` in a different database context.

The schema will be like

TableA (dbContextA)

```
Id   Name   Age   Town
```

TableB (dbContextB)

```
Id   Name   Age   JobTitle
```

Each table contains a large amount of information, such as around 100k rows.

What I want to do is to compare those two tables using the columns `Name` and `Age`, and make a synchronization.

Currently what I've done is retrieve data using `toListAsync()` for both tables,

```
var tableAData = await dbContextA.TableA.ToListAsync();
var tableBData = await dbContextB.TableB.ToListAsync();
```

and write the custom logic like using the `Where` clause.

But the problem is the performance and we cannot write a query using two different DB contexts at once.

As I mentioned, each table has a large amount of data and it's growing.
How can I compare those two tables in a better way with better optimization?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I compare those two tables in a better way with better optimization?

First consider whether EF is the right tool for the job.  The RDBMS may have a native replication capability, or you could use some ETL tool to perform the sync.

That being said, and given that using EF and client-side logic will never be nearly as fast as doing this directly on the databases, there are lots of ways to optimize this on the client.

LINQ doesn't have an optimizer, so if you want to implement a Hash Join or a Merge Join you have to code that yourself.  And you'll probably want to turn off DbContext change tracking and handle that yourself.  If your tables are very large you may have to avoid loading everything into memory and do a streaming merge join between two ordered queries.